# Identify Required Placeholders in GCMLE Model

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I have deployed a model a few weeks ago and I have lost track of which input features are required for the model (yes I know I should have kept better track of this).  When I run the following command

```
gcloud ml-engine predict \
--model $MODEL_NAME \
--version v1 \
--json-instances \
../test.json
```

I get the following err:

```
{
  "error": "Prediction failed: Exception during model execution: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details=\"input size does not match signature\")"
}
```

I know that my issue is because there is some "required" placeholder that I have not included in my json request (`test.json`) but I cannot figure out any way to retroactively find out which placeholder is missing.

The issue is the same as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976664/placeholder-tensors-require-a-value-in-ml-engine-predict-but-not-local-predict) where the poster was able to submit the prediction when he included the missing "threshold" tensor.

What would be the easiest way to look at the expected inputs for a given model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service itself does not yet allow you to query the signature of your model, so my recommendation is to use `saved_model_cli` where possible (assuming you didn't delete the original model). Something like:

```
gcloud ml-engine versions describe v1 --model census | grep deploymentUri
```

Which will output something like:

```
deploymentUri: gs://my_bucket/path/to/Servo/1488268526779
```

Now, use `saved_model_cli`:

```
saved_model_cli show --all --dir gs://my_bucket/path/to/Servo/1488268526779
```

Which will output something like:

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['serving_default']:
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
inputs['age'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (-1)
    name: Placeholder_8:0
inputs['capital_gain'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (-1)
    name: Placeholder_10:0
inputs['capital_loss'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (-1)
    name: Placeholder_11:0
inputs['education'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1)
    name: Placeholder_2:0
inputs['education_num'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (-1)
    name: Placeholder_9:0
inputs['gender'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1)
    name: Placeholder:0
inputs['hours_per_week'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (-1)
    name: Placeholder_12:0
inputs['marital_status'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1)
    name: Placeholder_3:0
inputs['native_country'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1)
    name: Placeholder_7:0
inputs['occupation'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1)
    name: Placeholder_6:0
inputs['race'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1)
    name: Placeholder_1:0
inputs['relationship'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1)
    name: Placeholder_4:0
inputs['workclass'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1)
    name: Placeholder_5:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
outputs['classes'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_INT64
    shape: (-1)
    name: predictions/classes:0
outputs['logistic'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (-1, 1)
    name: predictions/logistic:0
outputs['logits'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (-1, 1)
    name: add:0
outputs['probabilities'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (-1, 2)
    name: predictions/probabilities:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

Comment: Yes. I just found out about this myself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the tensorflow graph associated with your Saved Model. If you can print the graph (print the protobuffer in text format) or visualize with a tool, you can see the "signature_def" field within your graph. That should tell you the inputs and the outputs for your graph. You can compare what tensors you are sending in your request against the inputs that the graph expects.

Comment: I have the related saved_model.pb file. How would I print this in text format? I was able to display the model within tensorboard, but just curious about printing the protobuf file as well

Comment: Also struggling to find the "signature_def" field within my graph displayed in tensorboard